# Arrays.asList() vs Stream.collect()

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

Which one is more performant?

1. `Stream.of(stringArray).collect(Collectors.toList())`
2. `Arrays.asList(stringArray)`

Comment: They do different things. One results in a new list, copied from the array; the other results in a list backed by the array.

Comment: I would expect the second version to be more efficient, but there is only one way to be sure: measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a test by creating a very large array and calculate the elapsed time of the two technics that you mentioned, and then just compare the two elapsed time. here is an example:

```
String[] veryLargeStringArray = {"","",...};

long starttimelist1 = System.nanoTime();
List<String> list1 = Stream.of(veryLargeStringArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
long endtimelist1 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("list1 time : "+(endtimelist1-starttimelist1));
    
long starttimelist2 = System.nanoTime();
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(veryLargeStringArray);
long endtimelist2 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("list2 time : "+(endtimelist2-starttimelist2));
```

And in my opinion, the `Stream.of(veryLargeStringArray).collect(Collectors.toList())` is slower one because it has lot od sub-calls than `Arrays.asList(veryLargeStringArray)` which does just an instantiation of an `ArrayList`. And Finaly it depends on what you want to do in your code.

Comment: This is not how you measure performance. https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/829571

Comment: right, but I think with `nanoTime` is largely sufficient instead of `currentTimeMillis`

Comment: nanotime is not the problem here, the testing is.

Comment: The only correct statement is the last sentence: *it depends on what you want to do in your code*. Do you need a mutable list that changes the original array when modified or do you need a list of unspecified mutability that represents a copy of the original array…